# classes folder in target in maven project directory structure

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

When working `maven` project , `maven` sometimes generate classes folder in target directory. Sometimes it doesn't(may be create and delete immediately) ?.

What are the cases when it happen and when it doesn't ?.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project configuration. For general, the project packaging type will be one key factor. Like "pom" type or "bom" type, these types are just for describing a project meta like dependencies management, general plugin configurations and etc, which does not contain source code to do compiling. For jar package which contains source code, it will generate classes with compiling with default configuration of maven-compiler-plugin.

But for maven and its plugins, they are having many flexible ways to do configuration to change their abilities. For example, for compiling, you can even change your source code folder location and compilation location by using build-helper-maven-plugin. So this is still depending on your pom configurations.

For build-helper-maven-plugin, see https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html for more details.